# Make the background of 'Text' widget in tkinter transparent

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, transparent, python-3.5

I'm looking to add an image in the background of a Text widget in tkinter, but as far as I'm concerned, that is not possible. So, to work around this, I'm wondering if it is possible to make the background of a Text widget transparent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to make the background of the text widget transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It is anyway not possible to do so (without canvas), but if you really need it here's a hack:

- Go to *paint*
- Open the image you want and type in the text on it in whatever colour or font you want
- Set this image as your background in the frame that you want
- You can then add whatever buttons you want and place them wherever you want.

I know this is inconvenient but sometimes useful.